# Ruby on Rails: Why doesn't my formatting work when downloading XLS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel, ruby-on-rails-4, xls

Following RailsCast http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel?autoplay=true I am trying to format the xls download, but with my below code it doesn't format the xls file but just opens up Excel (with no data and no file opened).

`Mime_types.rb`:

```
Mime::Type.register "application/xls", :xls
```

`Contacts_controller`:

```
def index
  @contacts = Contact.where(user_id: session[:user_id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.csv { send_data @contacts.to_csv }
    format.xls
  end
end
```

`Contact` model:

```
def self.to_csv(options = {})
  CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
    csv << column_names
    all.each do |contact|
        csv << contact.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
    end
  end
end
```

`Index.xls.erb`:

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Surname</th>
    <th>Email</th>
  </tr>
  <% @contacts.each do |contact| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= contact.firstname %></td>
    <td><%= contact.surname %></td>
    <td><%= contact.email %></td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Can anyone tell me of the reason for this?

Can I note that when replacing the line `format.xls` in the controller `format.xls { send_data @contacts.to_csv(col_sep: "\t") }` it **does** download the XLS file but with no formatting.

Answer (score 0):

> but just opens up Excel (with no data and no file opened).

Perhaps, it has something to do with the fact that you send an html table, not spreadsheet data. In the railscast, Ryan generates some XML markup instead. Did you try that?

> when replacing the line format.xls in the controller format.xls { send_data @contacts.to_csv(col_sep: "\t") } it does download the XLS file but with no formatting.

Actually, what happens is that you download a CSV file that **pretends** to be an XLS file, but Excel is trying to be friendly to you and lets it pass. You get no formatting, because CSV is a data-only format. Not possible to embed formatting data there, so excel doesn't fetch any.

You'll get better results from generating the real thing instead of generating "fake" spreadsheets and hope that excel interprets them correctly. Check out [axlsx gem](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/randym/axlsx/file/README.md), for example.

Comment: Firstly, at 4:31 in the RailsCast Ryan uses a HTML table to format the Excel file, and I have tried the XML mark up but that results in a corrupt file. Thank you for explaining about the formatting issue, but I do not want to do this through a gem for now.

Comment: @BenSmith: I didn't watch the actual cast, I admit. :) But in the text section of below the video there's only xml version.

Comment: @BenSmith: "I don't want a gem" - yeah, I totally get that. We managed to last 3 years with a similar fake xls. But in the end, we had to implement the real thing.

Comment: @BenSmith: "XML mark up but that results in a corrupt file." - must that new version of excel doesn't want to put up with those hacks anymore.  :) Or you didn't generate correct xml.